# Left inverse implies right inverse in a finite ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

Let $R$ be a finite ring with identity $1$, and assume $\exists x,y\in R$ such that $ xy=1$. How can I show it implies $yx=1$?

Comment: $ya=yb\Rightarrow y(a-b)=0\Rightarrow xy(a-b)=0\Rightarrow a-b=0\Rightarrow a=b$

Comment: It is true for any noetherian ring, so it's true in this case!

Comment: It is true for finite monoids: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655186/in-a-non-commutative-monoid-is-the-left-inverse-of-an-element-also-the-right-in, so it is for finite rings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Hint: $xy=1$ implies that left multiplication by $y$ is one-to-one. Can you draw a conclusion whether or not there is a $z$ such that $yz=1$?

If so, you can complete the argument by showing that $z=x$.

Comment: Easy exercise: modify the proof for the case where $R$ is a finite $k$-algebra, where $k$ is field. Hard exercise: find a proof that works for both at once. (Hint: invent $\mathbb{F}_1$.)

Comment: @Zhen You may find of interest work by Vasconcelos, Armendariz et. al on analogous questions for finitely generated modules. For references see my [2007/12/12 sci.math post](http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/a6966e7c541821b5)

Comment: @rschwieb could you help me with this problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2163962/need-to-prove-that-a-given-nonzero-ring-r-with-no-zero-divisors-has-both-left It's similar.

Comment: @ALannister I added an answer I always give for that, since I can't seem to find a link to one I wrote previously.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** $\ $ As often occurs, this result on *numbers* is a special case of a result on *functions*. namely,  consider  $\rm\:x,y\:$ as left-multiplication maps $\rm\:f(r) = xr,\ g(r) = yr,\:$ then apply the following

**Lemma** $\rm\ fg = 1\ \Rightarrow\ gf = 1\ $ for maps $\rm\:f,g\:$ on a finite set $\rm\:R.$

$\rm(1)\ \ \ fg = 1\ \Rightarrow\ g\ is\ 1\!-\!1\:$ by $\rm\:f\:$ of $\rm\:g(a) = g(b)\ \Rightarrow\ a = b $

$\rm(2)\ \ \ g\ is\ 1\!-\!1\ \Rightarrow\ g\:$ is onto, since $\rm\:R\:$ is finite

$\rm(3)\ \ \ g\ is\ onto\ \Rightarrow\ gf = 1\:$ by $\rm\ a = g(b) = g(fg(b)) = gf(a)$

**Remark** $\ $ In fact we may view the ring as the set of such maps (left-regular representation), where the elements of $\rm\:R\:$ are essentially viewed as $1$-dimensional matrices. Then the above is analogous to a well-known result about matrices, e.g. see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3875/242) where I prove $\rm\ AB = I\:\Rightarrow\; BA = 1,\:$ or, equivalently, $\rm\:B\:$ injective  $\rm \Rightarrow$ $\rm\: B\:$ surjective, by exploiting the **pigeonhole principle**. See also other posts in that thread which clarify the fundamental role played by the pigeonhole principle. See also [this question on Dedekind-finite rings,](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33491/242) i.e. rings where $\rm\:xy = 1\:\Rightarrow\: yx = 1.$

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4252/242).

Answer (score 7):

Let $f_y\colon:R\rightarrow R,\ z\mapsto yz$ then:
$$f_y(z)=f_y(t)\iff yz=yt\Rightarrow x(yz)=x(yt)\Rightarrow (xy)z=(xy)t\Rightarrow z=t$$
hence $f_y$ is one to one. Now since $R$ is finite then the map $f_y$ is bijective hence there's a unique $z\in R$ s.t. $f_y(z)=yz=1$ so $x(yz)=(xy)z=z=x$ and conclude.

Comment: Another way to understand this argument is functionally: if left-multiplication by $y$ were non-injective, then post-composing it with left-multiplication by $x$ would necessarily yield a non-injective map, meaning multiplication by $xy$, or $1$, absurd.

Comment: How do you get $z = x$ in the last equality?

Comment: @Junglemath Maybe by multiplying $x$ on the left on both sides of the identity $yz=1$. Left hand side is $x(yz)=(xy)z=z$, and right hand side is $x \cdot 1 = x$. Hence $z=x$.