# in a finite ring, left inverse implies right inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a finite ring with $1\neq 0$. Suppose there are $x,y\in R$ such that $xy=1$. I have to prove that this implies $yx=1$.

I have read the question [Left inverse implies right inverse in a finite ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138541/left-inverse-implies-right-inverse-in-a-finite-ring) but I dont understand why $xy=1$ implies that left multiplication with $y$ is one to one. Could you explain? Thanks.