# How can we show that $I$ is an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $I$ the set of non-invertible elements of $R$.

If $(I,+)$ is an additive subgroup of $(R,+)$, then show that $I$ is an ideal of $R$ and so $R$ is local.

$$$$

I have done the following:

Since $(I,+)$ is an additive subgroup of $(R,+)$, we have that $\forall a,b \in I$ : $ab\in I$.

But how can we show that it holds that $ax\in I, \forall a\in I, \forall x\in R$ ?

Comment: If $ax$ were invertible, then $1=a(x(ax)^{-1})$, so that $a \notin I$.

Comment: Wait, why would $ab\in I$ from the fact that $I$ is a subgroup ? (I mean, it's true since $I$ is actually an ideal, but it's not immediate.)

Comment: @CaptainLama: Correct. In fact, it is not true in general that the non-invertible elements form an additive subgroup; in this problem, though, this is given as an assumption, but it seems that the OP has got a little confused about what she has to check.

Comment: If $ax$ is invertible there is a right and a left inverse. 
The right inverse is $(ax)(ax)^{-1}=1$ and the left inverse is $(ax)^{-1}(ax)=1$, or not? So, do we have to show also that $1=(\text{ something } ) a$, to conclude that $a\notin I$, or not? @Crostul

Comment: @rschwieb: The question that this is supposed to be a duplicate of is fairly different from this one: it has a very constraining assumption that is not to be found here, which makes that the proof found there not be applicable here. Could you please reconsider your close vote?

Comment: @MaryStar: out of your latest 40 questions, only 4 (i.e. 10%) have an accepted answer. Why? Keep behaving like this and people will stop answering your questions. I, for one, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that somewhere in your textbook $R$ is assumed to be commutative. Otherwise, the product of a non-invertible element with an arbitrary element of the ring [may turn out to be invertible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627562/can-the-product-of-two-non-invertible-elements-in-a-ring-be-invertible) (the examples given there are even stronger: they show that the product of two non-invertible elements might be invertible).

Let $a \in I$ and $x\in R$. Assume that $ax$ is invertible; there must exist, then, some $y \in R$ such that $(ax) y = 1$, which is equivalent to $a (xy) = 1$, which means that $xy$ is a right inverse for $a$, which will also be a left inverse because $R$ is commutative, so $a$ is invertible, which is a contradiction, therefore $ax$ is not invertible so $ax \in I$.

Comment: Ah ok... Is $I$ also the unique maximal right ideal of $R$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: Yes, it is: by assumption, $(I,+)$ is a subgroup of $(R,+)$. If $0 \ne 1$ (which is probably tacitly assumed), then [$R$ is a local ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_ring#Definition_and_first_consequences), so it will have a unique maximal ideal. Notice that $R/I$ is a field (this quotient essentially kills the non-invertible elements in $I$, leaving only the invertible ones). Since $R/I$ is a field, $I$ must be [maximal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximal_ideal#Properties). Since $R$ is local, $I$ must be unique then.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot!! :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Since $(I,+)$ is an additive subgroup of $(R,+)$, we have that $∀a,b∈I
> > : ab∈I.$

This reasoning is wrong. Moreover, you don't need to prove this statement. The product of a non-invertible element and any other element is non-invertible. Therefore it is immediate that $IR\subset R$. The set $I$ is by assumption a subgroup w.r.t. addition, hence an ideal.