# Product of non-invertible elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a unital ring (not necessarily commutative) and $x,y\in R$ be non-invertible elements.
Then is $xy$ non-invertible?
And how about the case $xy=yx$?

(postsclipt)
[Can the product of two non invertible elements in a ring be invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627562/can-the-product-of-two-non-invertible-elements-in-a-ring-be-invertible) :
This page gives a counterexample of the case $xy\neq yx$.

Comment: It's exactly as you said. Then how is the latter case?