# How does the 'reverse' implication follow here?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, banach-algebras, spectral-radius

I am totally confused with the following proof given in Simmons' *Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis* book (page: 312): Screenshot

Suppose $x$ is an arbitrary element in an **Banach algebra** and $\sigma(x)$ denotes its "**spectrum**" then Simmon claims:

[image: SS]

**My Confusion.** I am confused at the last line of the proof where he said

> $x^n-\lambda 1$ is singular $\iff x-\lambda_i 1$ is singular for at least one $i$

I'm assuming *singular* means **doesn't have a two sided inverse**.

'$\implies$' direction is okay: because if every $x-\lambda_i 1$ does have a two sided inverse (i.e., invertible) then their product $x^n-\lambda 1$ also has a two sided inverse.

But how did he claim **reverse** direction?? I mean if some $x-\lambda_i 1$ is singular (i.e., doesn't have a two sided inverse) it doesn't mean their product also be singular (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/627566/346939) is a counterexample of this fact (?) In this link $a$ and $b$ are not invertible but their product is invertible !)

Where am I making mistake? Can anyone please help me to clarify the above. Thanks.

**EDIT** Also I am really confused after noticing the link I mentioned. Doesn't that example show that the "reverse implication"  in Simmon is not necessarily true?

Comment: The short answer is: Everything works out here because $x - \lambda_i1$ commute with each other. Have posted a long answer below.

Comment: Thanks I just realised that… thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be any ring with $1$.

**Theorem.** Let $a, b \in A$ be elements that commute. Then, $ab$ is invertible iff $a$ and $b$ are invertible.

*Proof.* $(\Leftarrow)$ is standard.
$(\Rightarrow)$ Let $c$ be such that $(ab)c = 1 = c(ab)$.
The first equation gives $a(bc) = 1$.
The second gives $1 = cab = (cb)a$.
Thus, $a$ has a left and right inverse both. General theory tells us that it is then invertible. Similarly for $b$. $\Box$

Induction gives the following.

**Corollary 1.** Given pairwise commuting elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$, the product $a_1 \cdots a_n$ is invertible iff each $a_i$ is.

Taking "singular" to mean "non-invertible", the last result can be rephrased as:

**Corollary 2.** Given pairwise commuting elements $a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A$, the product $a_1 \cdots a_n$ is singular iff some $a_i$ is.

---

Now, this applies to your case with $a_i = x - \lambda_i1$, since the elements do commute.

Comment: Here $x$ is an arbitrary element in an Banach algebra.

Comment: @indrajit: have modified it now

Comment: Okay I understand actually here “$x-\lambda_i$”’s commutes with each other and so we can consider the subalgebra generated by them and then apply your argument! Right?

Comment: And the “link” I mentioned in my question is not giving a counter example to your argument because there the elements $a$ and $b$ don’t commute with each other!

Comment: @indrajit: Please see my modified answer. I have re-written it for two reasons: (1) It makes the process clearer. (2) There was a subtle error in my previous answer. When going from a ring to a subring, I might lose out on inverses. For example, $2 \in \Bbb Z \subset \Bbb Q$ is invertible in $\Bbb Q$ but not in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Also, yes, the counterexample in the link does not apply because here I'm focussing only on elements that commute.

Comment: Your argument in the previous post was also valid because we were generating polynomial algebra generated by $x$ in the ring which is commutative and contains the identity of the ring. Isn't that?

Comment: In the general situation we can consider the algebra $\Bbb{C}[a, b]$ which contains the identity also. ($a, b$ commuting elements)

Comment: @indrajit: I'm not completely sure if my earlier post was valid because: if any of the elements $x^n - 1$ or $x - \lambda_i1$ are invertible in $A$, I cannot see a way of guaranteeing that they are invertible in $\Bbb C[x]$ as well.

Comment: And I could consider the algebra obtained by adjoining the inverses if they are outside, but then I'd have to argue that it's still commutative.

Comment: Oh yes you are right!