# Are non-invertible elements of a monoid closed under multiplication?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Let $M$ be a monoid, and let $x$ and $y$ be non-invertible elements of $M$. Must the product $x*y$ also be non-invertible? I am especially interested in the case where neither $x$ nor $y$ have neither a right nor a left inverse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can the product of two non invertible elements in a ring be invertible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627562/can-the-product-of-two-non-invertible-elements-in-a-ring-be-invertible)

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $M$ to be the monoid of functions $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ under composition, take $y$ to be the function $y(k) = k + 1$, and take $x$ to be the function $x(k) = \text{min}(0, k-1)$. Then $y$ is not surjective and $x$ is not injective but their composition is the identity.

If $xy$ is invertible then $x$ necessarily has a right inverse and $y$ necessarily has a left inverse, so if we assume that either of those inverses doesn't exist then by taking the contrapositive, $xy$ is non-invertible.

However, this is true if $M$ is finite, and this follows from the fact that left inverses and right inverses are inverses in this case.