# In a non-commutative monoid, is the left inverse of an element also the right inverse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, monoid

Assume there is an element $a\in M$, where $M$ is a non-commutative monoid. If there exists $a b\in M$ such that $a * b = n$, where $n$ is the neutral, does it follow that $b * a = n$?

I want to say no, because the axioms which define a group shouldn't be redundant ($a * b = b * a = n$ is the 4th axiom). But the following logic seems to prove that the inverse is automatically commutative:

$b * n = b$

$b * (a * b) = b$

$(b*a) * b = b$

Thus for the last line to be true, $b*a$ has to evaluate to $n$.

Comment: Note, however that the group axioms as usually stated *are* redundant (this is generally stated as a remark or given as an exercise in basic algebra textbooks), in the sense that it is equivalent to state that there is a *left* identity, and that every element has a *left* inverse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes if $M$ is finite, no otherwise. For this you only have to consider for each $a\in M$, the function
$$\begin{align*}
T_a:M&\rightarrow M\\
x&\mapsto a*x
\end{align*}\text{.}$$
Then, if there is a $b$ such that
$$b*a=1\text{,}$$
this means that $T_a$ is injective since
$$\text{id}_M=T_b\circ T_a=T_{b*a}\text{.}$$
In this case, if $M$ is finite, this implies that $T_a$ is bijective and $T_b$ its inverse. Thus
$$b*a=1$$
due to
$$T_{b*a}=T_b\circ T_a\text{.}$$

However, when $M$ is infinite, this implication is false, i.e., there are functions that are injective and no surjective. For a concrete example with a monoid consider the monoid $M$ of functions $\mathbb{N}_0\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$ generated by the functions given by
$$
f:n\mapsto\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if }n=0\\
n-1& \text{ if }n\neq 0
\end{cases}\text{ and }
g:n\mapsto n+1\text{.}
$$
Then $f\circ g=\text{id}$ but not in the other way. (Note here how we are using the injective but not surjective function trick.)

Comment: I think neither $f\circ g=\text{id}$ nor $g\circ f=\text{id}$ is true.

Comment: @d0SO'N For any non-negative integer $n$, $f\circ g(n)=f(g(n))=f(n+1)=(n+1)-1=n=\mathrm{id}(n)$. Thus $f\circ g=\mathrm{id}$.

Comment: You're right. I skimmed over the non-negative part.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no. The [bicyclic monoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicyclic_semigroup) is a counter-example. However, in a finite monoid, the answer is yes.

Answer (score -2):

In your question, you called $M$ a non-commutative monoid. It should follow just from that, that the operations included in $M$ are not commutative. Thus, $a*b$ is not necessarily equal to $b*a$.

Normally, when someone twists my arm for an example of an associative but non-commutative binary operation, I answer "matrix multiplication."

Comment: I downvoted your answer because it is misleading. Typically "matrix multiplication" is a good place to look. However, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i).

Comment: Not helpful for the OP's question since that concerns a special case.  Even for multiplication of square matrices, $AB$ does not equal $BA$ in general, but $AB=I$ **does** imply $BA=I$.

Comment: Fair enough. I suppose saying "non-square matrix multiplication" might have enhanced what I was trying to convey.

Comment: @jasotastic Then there are other problems, such as not being a monoid... Again, multiplication of square matrices is typically a good example--just not in this instance.