# In a finite monoid, any left inverse is also a right inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $M$ be a finite monoid with identity $e$. If $x\in M$ has a left inverse $b$, I want to show that $b$ is also a right inverse.

There’s already a proof here [In a non-commutative monoid, is the left inverse of an element also the right inverse?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655186/in-a-non-commutative-monoid-is-the-left-inverse-of-an-element-also-the-right-in).

However, in my book the hint to this problem goes as follows. Since the set $\{x^n: n\in \mathbb N\}$ is finite, there are two distinct positive integers $l,k$ with $x^l=x^k$. But because $M$ is not a group there’s no cancellation law. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "But because $M$ is not a group, there's no cancellation law"...

But $x$ has a left inverse, so you can certainly cancel $x$ on the left: if $xr=xs$, then multiplying by $b$ on the left you get $bxr = bxs$, hence $er=es$, so $r=s$.

Remember, the cancellation law holds in groups *because* you have inverses. In a monoid, the existence of a (one-sided) inverse for $x$ means that you can cancel $x$ (on one side).

Assuming that $l\lt k$, from $x^l=x^k$ you get, multipying on the left by $b^l$, that $e=x^{k-l}$.

Now consider $xb$. Multiplying on the right by $x^{k-l}$ we get
$$xb = xbe = xbx^{k-l} = x(bx)x^{k-l-1} = xex^{k-l-1} = xx^{k-l-1}=x^{k-l}=e.$$
Now that we know that $b$ is a two-sided inverse, we may deduce that $b=x^{k-l-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer

Comment: For an alternative way of finishing the proof: $y:=x^{k-l-1}$ is clearly an inverse of $x$, in particular it's a right inverse, thus $$y=ey=bxy=be=b\,.$$