# Show finite ring has identity when for each $x$ there exists $y$ such that $xyx = x$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, finite-rings

I'm working through an old qualifying exam problem, and I'm stuck:

> Let $R \neq (0)$ be a finite ring such that for any element $x \in R$ there is $y \in R$ with $xyx = x$. Show that $R$ contains an identity and that for $a,b \in R$ if $ab = 1$ then $ba=1$.

---

On first glance, I suspected that $xy$ is a perfectly good identity, but this doesn't work. For example, in $\mathbb Z_6$, if $x = 3$, then $y \in \{1, 3, 5\}$ works, but $xy = 3 \neq 1$.

Once I have solved the first part, I can do the second part, using an argument from [another MSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/448697/121988).