# Are distinctions in definitions of "finite" material in, eg, topology or measure theory?

Tags: terminology, category-theory, definition, infinity

There are several definitions of "finite", like Dedekind's and Tarski's (Thanks to A.K. for point out the latter - first time I've heard of it): From the Wikipedia entry on [Finite Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_set):

(Richard Dedekind) Every one-to-one function from S into itself is onto.

(Alfred Tarski) Every non-empty family of subsets of S has a minimal element with respect to inclusion.

And there are more.

Do these distinctions matter when considering definitions of fundamental categories like topological spaces or measure spaces? For example,

In topology: [Why do we require a topological space to be closed under *finite* intersection?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4114/why-do-we-require-a-topological-space-to-be-closed-under-finite-intersection)

In [measure theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29): "A measure is continuous from above if [given measurable sets and closed under intersection] at least one set has *finite* measure," alternatively, in the definition of sigma-finite measures (same article).

Do the various definitions of finiteness lead to non-isomorphic or non-equivalent categories?

My question is not specifically about topology or measure theory, but these are basic definitions introduced at undergrad level, so I thought, better to understand the context via basic examples.

Comment: 1) For those of us not in the know, can you provide a
 reference to these definitions of "finite" per Dedekind or Tarski?
2) Not being familiar with either of these definitions, is there *any* example of a set which is "finite" in one definition and not in another?

Comment: @NKS, added Wikipedia links

Comment: @NKS I believe there are (at least) 16 different definitions of 'finite set' and no two are equivalent.

Comment: It should be pointed out that all these definitions are equivalent under the axiom of (countable) choice.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, although I find Choice interesting, I am primarily interested in constructive mathematics. Green & Tao in their arithmetic progressions paper write that they carefully avoid Choice, like a plague of some sort.

Comment: alan, I wrote this comment to point to the general public why these definitions are not the same. I might post an answer of my own later. I am still contemplating this.

Comment: How many of the 16 definitions equivalent in ZF+AD?

Comment: As far as I recall AD proves countable choice, so all Dedekind-finite sets are finite, and so all are equivalent. I should also point out that philosophically ZF+AD is a much harsher assumption than ZFC. I also don't really recall **16** definitions of finite. I recall about seven, but it's easy to generate more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The various non-equivalent notions of finiteness you allude to refer to definitions of 'finite set'. The concepts of finiteness you mention that are relevant to analysis (in general) refer to a number being finite. It is common-place in analysis to assume the standard models for Peano Arithmetic and the real numbers. Both of these are categorical models (that means that any two models are isomorphic). Then, all the elements in a model of PA are finite and all the elements in $\mathbb {R}$ are finite as well. It is common to consider the extended real numbers $\mathbb {R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$. Then $\pm \infty$ are by convention infinite numbers.

So, there is little (if any) relation between the different definitions of 'finite set' and the notion if measure theory of a set having finite measure or in topology for taking finite intersections. Finite in the former means a real number (and not $\pm \infty$) while in the latter it means 'perform intersection a finite number of times, counted using some natural number'.

Comment: I've seen this categorical defintion of Dedekind finite, no reference to sets: "An object A in a category C is Dedekind finite if all monos $j:A \to A$ are isomorphisms"  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66096/a-dedekind-pseudo-finite-set - correct?

Comment: yes, that's a possibility. Still, this makes no difference for finiteness issues of natural numbers or real numbers.

Comment: But what about for the spaces at issue, which are not numbers? Unions and intersection can be indexed by arbitrary functions right?

Comment: I'm not an expert on finiteness but as far as I know this has no implications to analysis. You are talking about performing a certain binary operation a finite number of times. Finite in this case means counted by some natural number, and these are categorical so there is only one meaning to that.

Comment: Not necessarily to analysis, but anywhere in math that "finite" is mentioned, whether in algebra, geometry etc. Eg, Hickman's "Dedekind Finite Fields" Bull Aus M Soc 1978. Dedekind-finite rings: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33491/why-are-dedekind-finite-rings-called-so...

Comment: as far as I know in the presence of AC all these different notions of finite are equivalent. It is likely that in intuitionistic mathematics such issues as you describe are important. At least in standard analysis AC is accepted.

Comment: It's all fun & games until you want to make a universal statement, such as Furstenberg's 1955 proof of the infinitude of primes via the topology on the integers generated by arithmetic progressions, where finite unions come into play. Imagine this is true with AC but false or unprovable without Choice and alternate definition of finite. That would be lame as opposed to universal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7219/discussion-between-ittay-weiss-and-alancalvitti)

Comment: I only saw your chat invite today.