# Left invertible matrices over rings with some special property

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

Suppose $R$ is a ring in which every left invertible element is invertible. Does this condition imply that every left invertible matrix in $\mathrm{M}_{n\times n}(R)$ is necessarily invertible?

Comment: No. This is Exercise 1.18 in Lam, *Exercises in Modules and Rings*, and has a solution there. (Btw, the "rings with some special property" are called *Dedekind-finite*. See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33491/why-are-dedekind-finite-rings-called-so).)

Comment: I think Lam even points out that erroneous proofs that Dedekind finiteness passes to matrix rings exist in the literature, so be careful, @mostafa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As user26857 brought up in his comment) a ring for which $xy=1$ implies $yx=1$ is called *Dedekind finite* or *directly finite.* This is readily confirmed to be equivalent to saying "every left invertible element is invertible."

Exercise 1.18 in Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* is to show there exists a Dedekind finite ring $R$ such that $M_2(R)$ is not Dedekind finite. A solution for it appears in the solution book *Exercises in modules and rings* on page 10.

Without verifying all the details, the construction goes like this. Let $w,x,y,z,s,t,u,v$ be symbols, and let $\begin{bmatrix}s&u\\t&v\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\z&w\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ under formal matrix multiplication. This provides us with four relations between the symbols, and then we look at the ring $R$ which is the quotient of the free $k$-algebra on these eight symbols subject to those relations.

To finish, it's shown that the product of the matrices in the reverse order does not make the identity (so $M_2(R)$ isn't Dedekind finite), and that $R$ is a domain (so it is Dedekind finite.)

If you'd rather learn directly from the original source, Lam credits it to this article:

> Shepherdson, J. C. *Inverses and zero divisors in matrix rings.* Proc. London Math.     Soc. (3) 1, (1951). 71--85. MR0041831 (13,7i)