# A ring where every left invertible elements are also right invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ a ring with identity element, are there necessary conditions that grant that every left invertible element is also right invertible (equivalently if an element is left/ right invertible must be also invertible)? Is there a name for such rings?

Comment: Do you mean, if exist $x,y \in R$ such that $xy = 1$ and $yx \neq 1$?

Comment: No, i mean if xy=1 then x and y are invertible.

Comment: Here are a bunch of conditions which each imply Dedekind finiteness: 1) If the nilpotent elements form an ideal, 2) all idempotents are central (includes commutative rings, local rings and domains) 3) There are no infinite families of orthogonal idempotents (includes Noetherian+Artinian rings); 4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such rings are called [Dedekind-finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33491/why-are-dedekind-finite-rings-called-so), i.e.,  the condition $ab=1$ implies $ba=1$.